# how to stop continous firing of automatic turrets after the enemies cross the collider?

Tags: unity-game-engine

i have a turret,as a game object when a enemy enters it's collison box,the turret starts firing towards it,the logic is when the enemy exits the collider,it should stop its firing ,and other problem is that when again an enemy enters the collison box i.e the second enemy,it gives me an exception ,"MissingReferenceException :the object of type 'transform' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.Your script should eihter be check if it is null or you should not destroy it",but i am checking if the list in not null in my code.here is my code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class TurretScript : MonoBehaviour {

public float shotInterval = 0.2f; // interval between shots
public GameObject bulletPrefab; // drag the bullet prefab here
public float bulletSpeed;

private float shootTime = 0.0f;
private List<Transform> targets;
private Transform selectedTarget;
private Transform myTransform;
private Transform bulletSpawn;

void Start(){
    targets = new List<Transform>();
    selectedTarget = null;
    myTransform = transform;
    bulletSpawn = transform.Find ("bulletSpawn"); // only works if bulletSpawn is a turret child!
}

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){
    if (other.tag == "enemy"){ // only enemies are added to the target list!
        targets.Add(other.transform);

    }
}

void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other){
    if (other.tag == "enemy"){
        targets.Remove(other.transform);
        Debug.Log("gone out");
    }
}

void TargetEnemy(){
    if (selectedTarget == null){ // if target destroyed or not selected yet...
        SortTargetsByDistance();  // select the closest one
        if (targets.Count > 0) selectedTarget = targets[0];
    }
}

void SortTargetsByDistance(){
    targets.Sort(delegate(Transform t1, Transform t2){ 
        return Vector3.Distance(t1.position, myTransform.position).CompareTo(Vector3.Distance(t2.position, myTransform.position));
    });
}

void Update(){
    TargetEnemy(); // update the selected target and look at it
    if (selectedTarget)
     { 
        // if there's any target in the range...
        Vector3 dir = selectedTarget.position - transform.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y,dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);// aim at it
        if (Time.time >= shootTime){// if it's time to shoot...
            // shoot in the target direction
            Vector3 lookPos = new Vector3(bulletSpawn.position.x,bulletSpawn.position.y,0);
            lookPos = lookPos - transform.position;
            float ang = Mathf.Atan2(lookPos.y,lookPos.x)*Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            GameObject b1 = Instantiate(bulletPrefab,new Vector3(transform.position.x,transform.position.y,5),transform.rotation)as GameObject;
            b1.rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(ang*Mathf.Deg2Rad),Mathf.Sin(ang*Mathf.Deg2Rad),0)*bulletSpeed;

            shootTime = Time.time + shotInterval; // set time for next shot
        }
    }
}
}
```

here is my enemy script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class EnemyScript : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform target;
public float speed = 2f;

public int Health;

public float GetHealth()
{
    return Health; 
}


void Update ()
{
    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);                                                                     
}

void TakeDamage(int damage){
    Health -= damage;
    if (Health <= 0) 
        Destroy(gameObject);
}


void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D otherCollider)
{
    PlayerControl shot = otherCollider.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerControl>();
    if (shot != null)
    {
        SpecialEffectsHelper.Instance.Explosion(transform.position);
        Destroy(shot.gameObject); 
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to check if the selected target is the target leaving the collider. You remove the target from the targets list but the `selectedTarget` var is still populated.

For the null ref exception. Are you using `Destroy()` to kill the target? `Destroy()` doesn't cause an `OnTriggerExit()` or `OnCollisionExit()` event call, the object is just gone.

edit: you can get around the lack of a call by adding an `OnDestroy()` function to the dying object that sets it's position to something well outside the level/view of the player. This way the target leaves the collider and then disappears rather than just disappearing in place.

Comment: selectedTarget is still populated as in?can u help me out ,i am stuck on these 2 things ,yes i am using a destroy() method to kill the object in the enemy script class.,updated the code for enemy class

Comment: "populated" as in not null. You just need a `if(other.transform == selectedtarget) {selectedtarget = null;}` in the `OnTriggerExit2D(...)`

Comment: it is giving me the same missing reference exception.

Comment: have you done the `OnDestroy()` changes as suggested? if so can we see the updated code?

Comment: but ,i am removing the enemy from the list also and checking if the value is null also.

Comment: you are removing them from the list when the `OnTriggerExit()` function is called. This function is not called when an object is destroyed. Therefore you will be left with a list that contains objects that do not exist, you then try to sort this list by accessing the attributes of those objects... accessing the attributes of an object which doesn't exist causes a null ref exception.

Comment: void onDestroy(GameObject other)
 {
  if (other.tag == "enemy"){
   targets.Remove(other.transform);
  }

 }
trying this thing

Comment: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDestroy.html it goes on the thing being destroyed so you can insert some logic/behaviour before it is removed from the scene. It's not one of the collision functions...

Comment: we need to check the selected target here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66928/discussion-between-safwan-and-lefty).